# Cordova debug: the specified file was not found

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova, debugging, emulation

I'm working on a Cordova project for Android using Visual Studio 2015. I can build my project without error and I can deploy it on Ripple.

But when I want to deploy on a real device or on an emulator, I'have always the same error: the specified file was not found. No more information in error list or output (using diagnostic output).

When I try to deploy on the emulator, the emulator receive the application and I can use it but when the app is lauched I have a pop-up from Visual Studio: "the specified file was not found" and I can't debug.

When I try to deploy on a real device, I have directy a pop-up: "there were deployment error. Continue ?" if I click on "yes", I have the popup "the specified file was not found".

I would like to have a solution and an explanation about this error.
Thank you in advance, I can't work with this kind of error except deploying on emulator and don't use debugging...

Comment: is this happening in new blank project or a existing one ?

Comment: the both, I'have this problem on 2 cordova project, a new project and an old. A colleague with the same code haven't problem...

Comment: check if you are able to run it using command line run `cordova run android` in cmd inside project folder.

Comment: No problem for running in emulator or device using this command line. The problem occurs when I want to debug using visual studio

Comment: Try cleaning cordova cache

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are missing a third party component (such as Android Studio), so Cordova is creating an Android project, but Android is not compiling that project into an Android app. That's why it deploys on Ripple (which just uses the first half of the build) but fails on the second half. I'd make sure that you do have Android home set up (check the path in Tools->Options->Tools for Apache Cordova). Otherwise, feel free to email your question + current project to vscordovatools@microsoft.com. I can take a look at it on my machine.

Linda Zhong, Tools for Apache Cordova PM
Lizhong@microsoft.com

Comment: The build and deploy doesn't fail but VS can't attach a debbuger to the app after application running.
I solve my problem updating VS cordova tools.
Thank you